# Thinning down a jquery focus script?

Tags: javascript, jquery, focus

I have a really simple jQuery script which when an input element is focused on, it expands its width to 250px (using the `focusin()` event), and when the focus is lost, it shrinks back to 200px using the `focusout()` event. But I'm not sure I'm using the most syntactically efficient code for what I'm trying to achieve. Here is my current code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input').focus(function() {
        $(this).animate({
            width: "250px"
        }, 500);
    });
    $('input').focusout(function() {
        $(this).animate({
            width: "200px"
        }, 500);
    });
});
```

To me however, this seems unnecessarily bulky. I've tried googling around, but I can't get the keywords right to find any results which help me. Surely there is a much simpler method to achieve such an effect, like a toggle? How would I achieve this?

Comment: could you post your html code ? it seems work to me

Comment: @maxisam there's nothing wrong with it, I'm asking if it's the most syntactically efficient way of achieving the goal I stated above.

Comment: lol, I miss read the whole thing.

Comment: if still on development,or plan to edit this code in the future, it is better to leave it as is. you would want a readable, understandable code to edit in the future. if you want to optimize your code for production release, better use a minifying tool. it will shorten the function names and variables, for you if your aim is lesser js file size.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see nothing wrong with what you've done.  If you feel you're repeating yourself too much, you might pull out some logic into a `animateWidth` function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    function animateWidth(element, width) {
        element.animate({ width: width }, 500);
    }

    $('input').focus(function () { animateWidth($(this), '250px'); })
              .focusout(function () { animateWidth($(this), '200px'); });

});
```

Comment: you can further lessen the clutter with shorter function and variable names on this one, although its not advisable during development stage.

Comment: +1. And although you didn't point it out explicitly, your code is more compact just by chaining the methods together.

Comment: This method seems alot more versatile than the one I am currently using. I'm assuming it could also be expanded to other elements much more easily as well. Cheers!

Comment: It doesn't seem to me like the common function is actually saving you anything here.  The original was one function call anyway.  Now, you're calling a common function just to call the original function.