# Can't select input field during jQuery animate?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-animate

This question is an indirect result of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8692240/1064923) about a animation script for a form.

It's just a simple jQuery script that animates a input field to a different width upon it being focused upon, and resets it to its original width upon defocusing like so:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('input').focus(function() {
    $(this).animate({
        width: "250px"
    }, 500);
});
$('input').focusout(function() {
    $(this).animate({
        width: "200px"
    }, 500);
});
});
```

The problem is that during the 500 milliseconds the input is animating, it's impossible to select the contents of that input if there is any in there - it may seem like a minor issue, but it is extremely irritating, and detracts from the overall usability of the form it is part of.

Is there any way around this? I couldn't find a single thing!

Comment: @check123. It's still irritating and that doesn't solve the issue.

Comment: I wasn't able to reproduce your problem in [this test case](http://jsfiddle.net/yahavbr/eqVQ7/) - I am able to select the text just fine. What browser are you using?

Comment: @ShadowWizard, I was able to reproduce it in your testcase using Google Chrome and Firefox! :) Set the animation speed to 500, then click on a field and immediately try to highlight it by dragging your mouse across the text.

Comment: @Antilogical that's exactly what I did, Chrome 16 here, and it works just fine.

Comment: @Shadow Wizard, oops, my mistake it DOES work in Chrome, but it doesn't in Firefox 9. Still confused!

Comment: Worked fine with both FF 8 and 9 (just upgraded) - maybe some addon?

Comment: @ShadowWizard, I tried disabling addons but it is still appearing, I'm really at a loss as to understand what is going on here.

Answer (score 0):

Could simply use CSS for such a simple transformation...

[jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/NotInUse/9yKrd/)

```
input {
width: 200px; 
transition: .5s;
-moz-transition: .5s;
-webkit-transition: .5s;
-o-transition: .5s;}

input:focus {
width: 250px;
transition: .5s;
-moz-transition: .5s;
-webkit-transition: .5s;
-o-transition: .5s; }
```

Comment: Looking good, what sort of browser compatibility has this got?

Comment: @Antilogical: Any browser that supports CSS3 (which includes most modern browsers now).

Comment: I can't afford to lose IE7/8/9 support, I suppose I could use a conditional IE statement so that the java-script method I'm currently using is for IE only, and use CSS transitions for every other browser, but that brings me back to my initial question about how to solve the non-selecting animate bug?